# Given a formula, solve for an unknown variable

Tags: algorithm, math

I have given the following Information.

```
  Amount = 425.50 
  Rate = 1.6951
  yRate = unknown
  xRate = yRate*1.6951
  Amount = yRate + xRate which is known 425.50
```

How can i get yRate based on the above Information?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about basic maths operations, not programming. If you're having a problem translating the maths operation into C# code, please include your code and describe the _specific_ problem that you're struggling with. Otherwise, this isn't a programming-related question.

Comment: What's the purpose of `Rate` if you're just going to hardcode 1.6951?

Comment: Btw `https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+425.5%3Dx*1.6951%2Bx`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you very much that's really helpful,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Amount = yRate + xRate;

// xRate is yRate * 1.6951
Amount = yRate + (yRate * 1.6951);
Amount = yRate * (1 + (1 * 1.6951));
Amount = yRate * (1 + 1.6951);
Amount = 2.6951 * yRate;

//    Amount  is 424.50
425.50 = 2.6951 * yRate;
yRate = 425.50 / 2.6951;
yRate = 157.8791139475344
```

So formula is

```
yRate = Amount / (1 + Rate);
```

Edit: If amount is `425.05` then yRate will be `157.7121442618085` using above formula.

Comment: What you want to compute here? Do you already have yRate?

Comment: It getting confused here now...what do you mean in your comment `my fault Amount is 425.05 yRate = 266.08` ?

Comment: I've added the formula for you. you can compute the the value using calculator based on your input. Let me know you need more details on that.

Comment: @kuka You have one unknown variable, and one equation. This is algebra 101. It works for all inputs

Answer (score 1):

yRate = Amount/2.6951 = 157.88